# How to get the fraction of a Bezier path from some percentage

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have a Bezier path and I want to get the Bezier path from some percent of the full Bezier path. For example, I have a Bezier path of a rectangle and I want to calculate the Bezier path of that rectangle for the percentage of 30%. Is there any way to calculate that fraction of the path?

Comment: Can you show what you mean using an image?

Comment: Cannot show with an image as of now, but it is like, say, I have a rectangular Bezier path and I want to show the progress bar on that Bezier path for some value between 0 to 1 . For that I need to calculate the percent length of the actual Bezier path and animate the CAShape layer position

Comment: Change `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` values. Ex `strokeStart = 0` and `strokeEnd = 0.3`

Comment: I need to animate the layer position not the stroke

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```swift
let firstPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)

let value: CGFloat = 0.5 // Your fraction

let secondPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.origin.y, width: rect.width * value, height: rect.height))
```

Comment: I need the path for the hexagon shape, so it can't be calculated in this way

Comment: Then you can use `path.bounds` to know the size of your `UIBezierPath`